# How we can remove listeners in React-native-navigation on app kill

Tags: socket.io, listener, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-fcm

How we can remove listeners in React-native-navigation on app kill . Because in the starting of the app there is no root component but just a class there is no componentWillUnMount. I need to remove some listeners on app kill for example react-native-fcm listeners and socket client listeners.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can unregister listeners when the root component is unmounted.

For example; in this root layout, you can do clean up when `navigation.playground.WelcomeScreen` unmounts.

```
Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    stack: {
      id: 'TEST',
      children: [
        {
          component: {
            name: 'navigation.playground.WelcomeScreen'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi I am using react-native-navigation V1 1.1.485 . The solution you provide me is in V2. Can you have any solution for V1

Answer (score 0):

The root component stack unmount as we move to another stack by using Navigation.setRoot there is no parent root here in this navigation where we can register or unregister the listeners.